# How to search for multiple OR with AND in Knex.js + PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

Say I have a table like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315127/what-happens-to-the-n-tables-you-insert-into-during-a-transaction):

```
create table object_properties {
  uuid id;
  uuid source_id; // the object which has this property
  string name; // the property name
  uuid value_id; // the property value object
}
```

I want to find all `object_properties`:

```
WHERE source_id IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AND name IN ['foo', 'bar']
OR WHERE source_id IN [6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2] AND name IN ['hello', 'world']
OR WHERE source_id IN [6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 5] AND name IN ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

How can I do this in [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#wherein) with PostgreSQL?

Doing this:

```
const knex = require('../knex')

console.log(knex('object_properties')
  .orWhereIn('source_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .whereIn('name', ['foo', 'bar'])
  .orWhereIn('source_id', [6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2])
  .whereIn('name', ['hello', 'world']).toString())
```

I get this:

```
select * from "object_properties" where "source_id" in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and "name" in ('foo', 'bar') or "source_id" in (6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2) and "name" in ('hello', 'world')
```

Not sure if that is correct, is that the correct SQL query? Do I need to use `raw` instead, and/or wrap the `OR` in parentheses or anything like that? Never really used `OR` before in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look to be missing the final part of your desired query  `OR WHERE source_id IN [6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 5] AND name IN ['x', 'y', 'z']` but other than that syntax wise it all looks correct. As for how the query will execute - In SQL `AND` takes precendence over `OR`, so without changing anything your query would execute like so:

```sql
select * from object_properties
where (
    source_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and name in ('foo', 'bar')
) or (
    source_id in (6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2) and name in ('hello', 'world')
)
```

which does appear to be what you want.

However when in doubt and for additional clarity it's always good to wrap things in parentheses, you can achieve that in `knex` by wrapping your `where` clauses in functions like so

```js
console.log(knex('object_properties')
  .where(function() {
    this.whereIn('source_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .whereIn('name', ['foo', 'bar']);
  })
  .orWhere(function() {
    this.whereIn('source_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .whereIn('name', ['hello', 'world']);
  })
  .orWhere(function() {
    this.whereIn('source_id', [6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 5])
    .whereIn('name', ['x', 'y', 'z']);
  }).toString());
```